# Ignore elements in certain tags when getting elements by id using VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have a vba module for extracting all the links in a page. I would however like to ignore all the links in certain tags such as `<header>` and `<footer>` (and all their child tags). Can anyone tell me how  can this be done?

```
Sub Fetch_click()

Dim LinkArr As Variant

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate Cells(1, 1).Text
While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

Dim i As Integer
i = 3

Set LinkArr = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each LinkObj In LinkArr
Cells(i, 1).Value = LinkObj.href
i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: This is untested, but in your loop, could you check for each `a`'s parent tag with something like `.ParentNode.NodeName = "header"` ?

Comment: I could, but there are lot of nesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use objects from the **Microsoft HTML Object Library** and the **Microsoft Internet Controls library** (add references to both!), e.g.

```
Sub StartTest()
Dim Browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    ' start browser
    Set Browser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Browser.Visible = True
    Browser.navigate "www.dauda.at"
    Set HTMLDoc = Browser.document

Dim ECol As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim IFld As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    ' search all <a> tags
    Set ECol = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each IFld In ECol

        ' etc ...

    Next IFld

    ' clean up
    Set IFld = Nothing
    Set ECol = Nothing
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    Browser.Quit
    Set Browser = Nothing
End Sub
```

Checking where your `<a>` tag is sitting, can be as easy as inspecting the `IFld.ParentNode.nodeName` to get the tag of the enclosing parent.

If it is unclear how deeply nested your `<a>` is, you can make use of a recursive function examing the next higher parent all the way up to the document root (`"#document"`) or the contained `"HTML"`, e.g.

```
Function BadParentRec(TestFld As MSHTML.IHTMLElement) As Boolean
Dim MyTag As String, MyTempResult As Boolean

    BadParentRec = False
    MyTag = TestFld.ParentNode.nodeName
    ' Debug.Print MyTag

    If MyTag = "#document" Then
        MyTempResult = False                                ' lowest level is good
    ElseIf MyTag = "XXX" Then                               ' your own criteria for bad tags go here
        MyTempResult = True                                 ' send "bad" back up the recursion chain
    Else
        MyTempResult = BadParentRec(TestFld.parentElement)  ' next level down
    End If

    BadParentRec = MyTempResult

End Function
```

... so inside the `For Each` loop you would say

```
    If Not BadParentRec(IFld) Then
        Debug.Print Ifld.href                ' check here for href = ""
    End If
```